# Transclude all child elements inside a component with AngularJS 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this html

```
<parent>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

How can I transclude all `<child>` elements inside the `<parent>` element?

Here's what I have so far :

```
angular.module('foo', [])
   .component('parent', {
      restrict: "E",
      template: '<!-- template -->' +
                '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
      transclude  : true,
      controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        /* code */
      }
   })
   .component('child', {
      restrict: "E",
      require: {
        parent: '^parent',
      },
      template: '<!-- template -->',
      controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        /* code */
      }
   })
;
```

However, only the first `<child>` is transcluded.

How can I have all children transcluded?